# How to load xml file into Hive

Tags: xml, hadoop, hive

Im working on Hive tables im having the following problem. I am having more than 1 billion of xml files in my HDFS. What i want to do is, Each xml file having the  4 different sections. Now i want to split and load the each part in the each table for every xml file

Example :

```
            <?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>

            <section1>
                <id> 1233222 </id>
               // having lot of xml tages 
            </section1>

            <section2>
               // having lot of xml tages 
            </section2>

            <section3>
               // having lot of xml tages 
            </section3>

            <section4>
               // having lot of xml tages 
            </section4>

            </xml>
```

And i have the four tables

```
        section1Table

        id       section1    // fields 

        section2Table

        id       section2

        section3Table 

        id       section3

        section4Table

        id       section4
```

Now i want to split and load the data into each table.

How can i achieve this . Can anyone help me

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test(name STRING) LOCATION '/user/sornalingam/zipped/output/Tagged/t1';\


SELECT xpath (name, '//section1') FROM test LIMIT 1 ;
```

but i got the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"name":"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>"}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have several options:

- Load the XML into a Hive table with a string column, one per row (e.g. `CREATE TABLE xmlfiles (id int, xmlfile string)`. Then use an [XPath UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+XPathUDF) to do work on the XML.
- Since you know the XPath's of what you want (e.g. `//section1`), follow the instructions in the second half of [this tutorial](https://communities.intel.com/community/datastack/blog/2013/08/15/hadoop-tutorials-ingesting-xml-in-hive-using-xpath) to ingest directly into Hive via XPath.
- Map your XML to Avro as described [here](http://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/bose-june26-405pmroom230cv3-24148869) because a [SerDe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe) exists for seamless Avro-to-Hive mapping.
- Use XPath to store your data in a regular text file in HDFS and then ingest that into Hive.

It depends on your level of experience and comfort with these approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test(name STRING) LOCATION '/user/sornalingam/zipped/output/Tagged/t1'

tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1", "skip.footer.line.count"="1");
```

And then use xpath function