# XML Data load in Hive

Tags: hive

I have a xml file like

```
<document>
<site>  
<url>htp://www.abc.com/</url>
<category>Sports</category>
<usercount>120</usercount>  
<review>good site</review>
</site> 
<site>
<url>http://www.fb.com/</url>
<category>Social</category>
<usercount>100</usercount>  
<review>Addictive</review>
</site> 
<site>  
<url>http://www.google.com/</url>
<category>Web Search</category>
<usercount>1000</usercount>  
<review>helpful</review>
</site> 
</document>
```

I am creating table by below script.

```
    create table IF NOT EXISTS xmltest(url STRING,category STRING,usercount STRING,review STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.url"="/document/site/url/text()",
"column.xpath.category"="/document/site/category/text()",
"column.xpath.usercount"="/document/site/usercount/text()",
"column.xpath.review"="/document/site/review/text()")
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<document",
"xmlinput.end"="</document>");
```

when selecting all data, out put is coming like

```
'<string>htp://www.abc.com/http://www.fb.com/http://www.google.com/</string>    <string>SportsSocialWeb Search</string> <string>1201BillionSeveral Billions</string>    <string>good siteAddictiveVery helpful</string>'
```

I want output as 
'htp://www.abc.com/  Sports   120    good site'
'http://www.fb.com/  Social   100    Addictive'

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852166/how-to-load-xml-file-into-hive

Comment: you have to create one more table an insert data into it. as in one go it is not possible with SERDE  you are using to lade data or create your own SERDE

Comment: Hi Sandeep, Thanks for the tip. Is there any apache provided SerDe that cab be used to create the table instead of writing our own SerDe?